# I defined a hash, but exists function throws an error saying it's not a hash

Tags: perl

This problem seems to be one of scope.  The line with the exists function on it throws an error saying that it's not receiving a hash as an argument.  How can I make so the value being passed to the exists function is my hash?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open FH, 'test_out' or die $!;

my %pn_codes = ();

while(<FH>) {
    if(/.*PN=(\d*)/) {
        my $pn = $1;
        if(exists %pn_codes{$pn}) {
            print($pn, "exists");
        } else {
            %pn_codes{$pn} = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `if(exists $pn_codes{$pn}) {` instead (switch `%` to `$`). Here too: `$pn_codes{$pn} = 1;`

Comment: Actually, the error says it's not a hash *element*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify `exists` on a scalar `$hash{key}`

```
if (exists $pn_codes{$pn}) {
```

However, you're essentially creating a `%seen` style hash which can be simplified to just:

```
while (<FH>) {
    if (/.*PN=(\d*)/) {
        my $pn = $1;
        if (! $pn_codes{$pn}++) {
            print($pn, "exists");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can even avoid the global var: `if (my ($pn) = /.*PN=(\d*)/)`

Answer (score 1):

perl [`diagnostics`](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) can be useful,

```
perl -Mdiagnostics -c script.pl
exists argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or a subroutine at c line 13 (#1)
    (F) The argument to exists() must be a hash or array element or a
    subroutine with an ampersand, such as:

        $foo{$bar}
        $ref->{"susie"}[12]
        &do_something

Uncaught exception from user code:
        exists argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or a subroutine at c line 13.
 at c line 13
```